# set a value with jq names with full stops in them

Tags: shell, jq

I'm wondering how i can escape the newValue so jq replaces the value in :

```
#!/bin/sh

test="{ \"one.one\" : { \"version\" : \"0.0.1\" }, \"two.two\" : { \"version\" : \"0.0.2\" } }"
newvalue="3.3.3"
newjson=$(echo $test | jq '."two.two".version = "$newvalue" ')
echo $newjson
```

outputs:

```
{ "one.one": { "version": "0.0.1" }, "two.two": { "version": "$newvalue" } }
```

none of the escapes i tried `\"` `\'` around $newvalue seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to use a variable, it can't be in quotes. Replace

```
"$newvalue"
```

with

```
$newvalue
```

---

Secondly, you never set `$newvalue` in the jq program. To achieve that, you can use the following:

```bash
--arg newvalue "$newvalue"
```

Comment: thank you !! i didn't even know about the --arg option..